# android list layout unable to achieve

Tags: android, textview

I want to achive the following layout in a list view of quote texts.

[image]

i am trying for orange background instead of grey and green text background instead of white:

the following is the xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/gridview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:numColumns="1"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:gravity="center"

/>


 the file quote_text.xml
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_dark"   >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/quotetext1"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:paddingRight="20dp"
        android:paddingTop="20dp"
        android:paddingBottom="20dp"
        android:textSize="15dp" >
    </TextView>

</LinearLayout>
```

what i get is the following

[image: result sanpshot]

My code in the getView() is

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        TextView textView;

    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
         View gimkan = inflater.inflate(R.layout.quote_text, parent, false);
       textView = (TextView) gimkan.findViewById(R.id.quotetext1);
    }
    else
    {
        textView = (TextView) convertView;
    }

    textView.setText(mThumbIds[position]);
    return textView;
}
```

I also tried using  the following as per the answer of dieter_h

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/gridview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
/>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_dark">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/quotetext1"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    tools:text="kfjjkdshf jkhs jkdhs sdjh jksdh s sdjhfjksdh kjsdfh"
    android:padding="20dp"
    android:layout_margin="15dp"
    android:textSize="15dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

[image: Screenshot with listview]

Still it does show as needed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your XML layouts to these:

ListView

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="16dp"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_dark">
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:dividerHeight="16dp"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

ItemView

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="8dp"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_green_dark"
    android:textSize="14sp"/>
```

And this is what you should get:

[image]

Comment: You got it. Why we have to use <FrameLayout>. In many places i have searched its no where mentioned

Comment: You might want to use margin for your ListView at first place BUT as my experience, Android doesn't take margins into account if the view which has margins doesn't have a parent, so you can either wrap your ListView with a `FrameLayout` (or any `ViewGroup` inherited classes, `LinearLayout`, `RelativeLayout`..., but `FrameLayout` is the lightest one after all, so I choose `FrameLayout`) then set padding for it OR don't set padding for the `FrameLayout` but margin for the ListView. Hope you get it ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try to change `quote_text.xml`:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_dark">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/quotetext1"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    tools:text="kfjjkdshf jkhs jkdhs sdjh jksdh s sdjhfjksdh kjsdfh"
    android:padding="20dp"
    android:layout_margin="15dp"
    android:textSize="15dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Change GridView to ListView:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/gridview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

Comment: It shows the same thing again. Entire green color with text. Is it anything to do with `View gimkan = inflater.inflate(R.layout.quote_text, parent, false);`

Comment: I tried `View gimkan = inflater.inflate(R.layout.quote_text, null)`. no change. its the same (complete green with text)

Comment: No change in the layout. It shows the same (green screen with text). It does not show the text you have mentioned tools.text. it shows the the text from setText()

Comment: If i check this xml in android studio. it shows what is expected green text box on orange background. But when i compile and run it doesnt.

Comment: edited my question with your input. it still does not show as i wanted